# How to get a windows service to execute the same code using a timer vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, service, dictionary, windows-services

**EDIT**

Turns out there is an exception:

[image: dictionary error]

What i want to happen is for the dictionary keys and items to be overwritten each time it is executed, as the data needs to be up to date. Is there any way i can do this to resolve my problem?

Comment: Now that you can see the exception, you have the answer, right?

Comment: Im guessing i need to get the dictionary to allow records to be overwritten? however im not to sure how i can do this.

Comment: You _can't_ do that. You have to check first to see if the dictionary already "contains" the entry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this in a service (I tend to follow a pretty similar pattern when writing services, however I was unsure on your time delay - Did you want 10s between file creations, or to start creating a file every 10s?  It is a subtle difference, but imagine what would happen if creating the file took say 30s...)

```
Private Shared ReadOnly SleepTime As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)
Private _stopService As Boolean
Private _thread As Thread

Public Sub OnStart()

    _stopService = False

    _thread = New Thread(AddressOf DoWork)
    _thread.Name = "File Creation Thread"
    _thread.Start()

End Sub

Public Sub OnStop()

    _stopService = True
    _thread.Join()

End Sub

Private Sub DoWork()

    While Not _stopService

        GetInfo()
        GetUsers()
        GetProcess()
        GetServices()
        GetCPU()
        GetMem()
        WriteXML()

        Thread.Sleep(SleepTime)

    End While

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This most likely explanation appears to be that an exception is thrown. Set your interval to something longer, and set it before you enable your timer. Then attach to your service with a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: turns out it was throwing up an exception. ive attached a screenshot of it in my post. i'm slightly unsure if i now need to work out how to overwrite the contents of a dictionary each time it is executed?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to re-new your containers each time. Not doing that is the reason for your exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Public Sub DoNextExecution()
    SyncLock Me
        thisTimer.Stop()

        Try
            GetInfo()
            GetUsers()
            GetProcess()
            GetServices()
            GetCPU()
            GetMem()
            WriteXML()
        Catch ex as Exception
            ' TODO: Log the exception somehow!
        End Try

        ' Another execution cycle begins.

        thisTimer.Start()
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Note: you don't need to set the timer's AutoRestart to true or call Stop() if you are going to call the timer's Start method every tick.

Comment: turns out it was throwing up an exception. ive attached a screenshot of it in my post. i'm slightly unsure if i now need to work out how to overwrite the contents of a dictionary each time it is executed?

Comment: Well you could add a line like: `If dict.ContainsKey(1) Then dict.Remove(1)`  right before your Add.  Or you could do a dict.Clear() at the beginning of each run.  It kind of depends on *how* you want the dictionary updated.